# To Create Multiple Directories using mkdir() in Php

Tags: php, cpanel

I am working on a social network website, in which multiple directories are created on signup. Here is the code I am using:

```
$path = "fb_users/Organization/" . $user . "/Profile/";
$path2 = "fb_users/Organization/" . $user . "/Post/";
$path3 = "fb_users/Organization/" . $user . "/Cover/";
mkdir($path, 0, true);
mkdir($path2, 0, true);
mkdir($path3, 0, true);
```

The code is working good on my localhost, but when I am using the same code on cPanel hosting, the code only creates `fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com` (let $user = fb@abc.com). It's not creating three more folders. Will anyone please get me out of this?

Directory before code:

```
/fb_users/Organization
```

After running code on localhost:

```
/fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com/Cover
/fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com/Post
/fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com/Profile
```

Same code running on hosting using cPanel:

```
/fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com (only this directory is created)
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue of the newly created folder. What is result of fileperms() on the newly created folder?

Comment: `mode = 0` means the directory is not writable, so it can't create the subdirectories.

Comment: And mode is ignored on Windows machines, which is why it works on localhost and not cPanel host.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with phpMyAdmin (which is an application for managing a MySQL database installation).

Answer (score 5):

When you specify `mode = 0` on a Unix server, it will create the top-level directory `/fb_users/Organization/fb@abc.com` with no read or write permissions, even for the owner. So it won't have permission to create the subdirectories. Use `0700` to give the owner full permissions, but not allow anyone else to access it.

```
mkdir($path, 0700, true);
mkdir($path2, 0700, true);
mkdir($path3, 0700, true);
```

Comment: Thanks ! Working Properly !

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the second parameter to 0700.

Edit: Barmar beat me to it, with a better explanation.

Comment: Got it ! Working properly !